# Problemas al comprimir Zip un archivo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Tengo un loader de archivos con HTML y un localhost en Python que cuando el usuario selecciona un archivo se guarda en la carpeta de "subidos", pero tengo unos problemas para hacer zip de ese archivo:

1. No me lo esta seleccionando
2. Una vez creado el `.zip` no se guarda dentro de esa carpeta "subidos".

Los archivos HTMl no están del todo proligos, pero por ahora solo me quiero enfocar en esta funcionalidad aquí les dejo mis archivos: [link de github](https://github.com/josesilva27/ozone2/upload/master)

Traté de comprimir usando `os.path.join(pathname,filename)` dentro de `myzip.write()` y al colocar `pathname=filename` si se comprimió, pero literalmente me creaba la ruta dentro. Ejemplo al abrir el `.zip` había una carpeta dentro de otra hasta que la ruta era

> users>desktop>codes>prueba>subidos>archivo.jpg

Aquí esta el código en Python

```
import os               
from zipfile import ZipFile
from flask import Flask , request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app= Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    return render_template ("inicio.html")

@app.route('/archivos')
def archivos():
    return render_template ("archivos.html")

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './subidos'
app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'] = './Descargas'

@app.route("/uploader", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f= request.files['archivo']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        if os.path.exists("Descargas") == True:
            if len(os.listdir(os.getcwd()+'\\Descargas')) == 0:
                print("carpeta vacia :c")
        else:
            os.mkdir ("Descargas")

        rutaSubidos= os.getcwd()+'\\subidos'
        archivo = open(rutaSubidos+'\\'+ filename,'r')
        
        myzip = ZipFile('archivo.zip','w')
        myzip.write (filename)
        myzip.close()
        
        archivo.close()

        return 'subido exitosamente'
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que necesites la ruta absoluta para ubicar al archivo, y aún así, según la documentación del método [`write()`](http://myzip.write%20(filename,%20os.path.basename(filename))) puedes usar el parámetro `arcname` y establecer el nombre del archivo dentro del zip:

Ejemplo:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

filename = 'c:\\esta\\es\\una\\ruta\\absoluta\\archivo.zip'

myzip = ZipFile(filename,'w')
myzip.write(filename, os.path.basename(filename))
myzip.close()
```

Comprimimos un archivo con un path absoluto `filename`, pero que se guarde solo con el nombre `os.path.basename(filename)`, obviamente habrá que tener cuidado ya que de esta forma no puedes comprimir un mismo nombre de archivo que estuviera en carpetas distintas.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias esto me ayudo mucho , pero por ejemplo en el caso de múltiples archivos me pasa lo mismo que me da toda la ruta completa , cuando solo quisiera que fuera el directorio al que estoy tratando de comprimir . llamada funcion:empaquetar2(os.getcwd()+'\\subidos',os.path.basename(rutaSubidos)) donde la primera es la ruta del directorio así lo he visto en internet tal cual pero a mi me mustra la ruta absoluta del directorio que quiero comprimir

Comment: @Jose_Silva,  `write` puede recibir dos datos, el primero es la ruta absoluta o eventualmente relativa del archivo quieres comprimir, el segundo parámetro es el nombre con el que quieres guardarlo, en este es donde deberías quitar la parte de la ruta del archivo. Si quieres, chequea este ejemplo: https://repl.it/@pmoracho/ZipWithoutPaths